# svg background not painted qt

Tags: c++, qt, svg, qgraphicssvgitem

I am trying to display the contents of a .svg file in a QGraphicsView in Qt. For this I use:

```
QImage image (SCENEWIDTH, SCENEHEIGHT, QImage :: Format_ARGB32);
QSvgRenderer * renderer = new QSvgRenderer (path_img); //path of .svg file
QPainter painter (& image);
renderer-> render (& painter);
QGraphicsSvgItem * f = new QGraphicsSvgItem ();
f-> setSharedRenderer (renderer);

scene2-> setSceneRect (QRectF (0, 0, SCENEWIDTH, SCENEHEIGHT))
scene2-> addItem (f);

ui-> view-> setScene (scene2);
ui-> view-> show ();
```

The content of the svg consists of several lines to draw that are painted over a background image, loaded into the svg using:

```
<image id = "img1" href = "sample.png" />
```

The sample.png image is in the same path as the .svg file I want to display. The browser paints the image correctly if I open it directly from the browser, but nevertheless in the QGraphicsView only the lines are painted, but not the background image.

I have tried many options from searches, but I can not find the reason why this is happening. Thanks for the help

This is a sample SVG file, the image sakura.jpg should be in the same directory as svg file:

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" style="background-color:black" width="1920" height="1080">
            <style>
.blue  { stroke:blue;  stroke-width:9; fill:transparent; }
.red   { stroke:red;   stroke-width:10; fill:transparent;}
            </style>

   <g class="zone05" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(0,0,0) scale(1)">
      <image id="img05" href="sakura.jpg"/>
      <path class="red" d="M 851 444 m -19 -19 l 38 38 m 0 -38 l -38 38" />
      <path class="red" d="M 475 520 m -19 -19 l 38 38 m 0 -38 l -38 38" />
      <path class="red" d="M 1047 790 m -19 -19 l 38 38 m 0 -38 l -38 38" />
      <path class="blue" d="M 1270 638 m -19 -19 l 38 38 m 0 -38 l -38 38" />
   </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Did you add `QT += svg` in `.pro` file ?

Comment: please share the .svg

Comment: @Parisa.H.R I do not think that is the error since otherwise it would have indicated that it cannot compile.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to be sure .

Answer (score 0):

I try your code and it works but the only things that I added to your code,  I put `svg` file path inside `QString` and I add `QGraphicsScene`that I'm sure you have this too. I push it in this repo for you to test it :

https://bitbucket.org/parisa_HR/stackoverflow/src/master/

```
   QGraphicsScene *scene2 = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    QImage          image(scene2->width(), scene2->height(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    QSvgRenderer   *renderer = new QSvgRenderer(QString(":/svgs/fire.svg"));      // path of .svg file
    QPainter        painter(&image);
    renderer->render(&painter);
    QGraphicsSvgItem *f = new QGraphicsSvgItem();
    f->setSharedRenderer(renderer);

    scene2->setSceneRect(QRectF(0, 0, scene2->width(), scene2->height()));
    scene2->addItem(f);

    ui->view->setScene(scene2);
    ui->view->show();
```

[image]

**updated** :

I changed my SVG file and add one `jpeg` file as an example of background.

but it works.

[image]

**I also try png too.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   id="Capa_1"
   enable-background="new 0 0 512 512"
   height="512"
   viewBox="0 0 512 512"
   width="512"
   version="1.1"
   sodipodi:docname="fire.svg"
   inkscape:version="1.1 (ce6663b3b7, 2021-05-25)"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs
     id="defs15" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview13"
     pagecolor="#505050"
     bordercolor="#eeeeee"
     borderopacity="1"
     inkscape:pageshadow="0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35976819"
     inkscape:cx="144.53751"
     inkscape:cy="523.94848"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="670"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="27"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="Capa_1" />
  <image
     width="512.33936"
     height="512.33936"
     preserveAspectRatio="none"
     xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA+gAAAPoCAIAAADCwUOzAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAA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"
     id="image1016"
     x="-3.6043305"
     y="1.78023" />
  <g
     id="g10"
     transform="matrix(0.31264363,0,0,0.31264363,30.205716,291.36914)">
    <path
       d="M 454.22,313.78 C 454.22,423.25 365.47,512 256,512 146.53,512 57.78,423.25 57.78,313.78 c 0,-37.65 10.49,-72.86 28.74,-102.83 0,0 25.24,53.86 68.6,36.45 17.05,-6.84 36.46,-26.05 18.16,-57.74 -19.74,-34.17 -9.27,-82.43 34.24,-100.9 C 256,68.18 256,0 256,0 c 4.88,3.13 76.59,50.67 50.28,111.89 -15.72,36.58 -17.6,80.91 15.09,90.71 39.12,11.74 59.77,-42.54 59.77,-42.54 44.59,36.34 73.08,91.7 73.08,153.72 z"
       fill="#fcd703"
       id="path2" />
    <path
       d="M 454.22,313.78 C 454.22,423.25 365.47,512 256,512 V 0 c 4.88,3.13 76.59,50.67 50.28,111.89 -15.72,36.58 -17.6,80.91 15.09,90.71 39.12,11.74 59.77,-42.54 59.77,-42.54 44.59,36.34 73.08,91.7 73.08,153.72 z"
       fill="#fe9100"
       id="path4" />
    <path
       d="m 351.2,416.82 c 0,59.92 -50.51,95.18 -95.2,95.18 -52.56,0 -95.17,-42.61 -95.19,-95.16 0,-0.02 0,-0.02 0,-0.04 -0.24,-19.81 4.04,-43.24 15.97,-70.43 l 38.91,11.38 c 0,-39.56 21.06,-66.17 40.31,-82.23 16.18,-13.48 31.1,-19.52 31.1,-19.52 4.88,58.84 39.4,93.06 51.47,114.71 10.45,18.76 12.63,30.39 12.63,46.11 z"
       fill="#ff7b49"
       id="path6" />
    <path
       d="M 351.2,416.82 C 351.2,476.74 300.69,512 256,512 V 275.52 C 272.18,262.04 287.1,256 287.1,256 c 4.88,58.84 39.4,93.06 51.47,114.71 10.45,18.76 12.63,30.39 12.63,46.11 z"
       fill="#fd435b"
       id="path8" />
  </g>
  <g
     id="g852"
     transform="matrix(0.31264363,0,0,0.31264363,289.55613,310.41629)">
    <path
       d="M 454.22,313.78 C 454.22,423.25 365.47,512 256,512 146.53,512 57.78,423.25 57.78,313.78 c 0,-37.65 10.49,-72.86 28.74,-102.83 0,0 25.24,53.86 68.6,36.45 17.05,-6.84 36.46,-26.05 18.16,-57.74 -19.74,-34.17 -9.27,-82.43 34.24,-100.9 C 256,68.18 256,0 256,0 c 4.88,3.13 76.59,50.67 50.28,111.89 -15.72,36.58 -17.6,80.91 15.09,90.71 39.12,11.74 59.77,-42.54 59.77,-42.54 44.59,36.34 73.08,91.7 73.08,153.72 z"
       fill="#fcd703"
       id="path844" />
    <path
       d="M 454.22,313.78 C 454.22,423.25 365.47,512 256,512 V 0 c 4.88,3.13 76.59,50.67 50.28,111.89 -15.72,36.58 -17.6,80.91 15.09,90.71 39.12,11.74 59.77,-42.54 59.77,-42.54 44.59,36.34 73.08,91.7 73.08,153.72 z"
       fill="#fe9100"
       id="path846" />
    <path
       d="m 351.2,416.82 c 0,59.92 -50.51,95.18 -95.2,95.18 -52.56,0 -95.17,-42.61 -95.19,-95.16 0,-0.02 0,-0.02 0,-0.04 -0.24,-19.81 4.04,-43.24 15.97,-70.43 l 38.91,11.38 c 0,-39.56 21.06,-66.17 40.31,-82.23 16.18,-13.48 31.1,-19.52 31.1,-19.52 4.88,58.84 39.4,93.06 51.47,114.71 10.45,18.76 12.63,30.39 12.63,46.11 z"
       fill="#ff7b49"
       id="path848" />
    <path
       d="M 351.2,416.82 C 351.2,476.74 300.69,512 256,512 V 275.52 C 272.18,262.04 287.1,256 287.1,256 c 4.88,58.84 39.4,93.06 51.47,114.71 10.45,18.76 12.63,30.39 12.63,46.11 z"
       fill="#fd435b"
       id="path850" />
  </g>
  <g
     id="g862"
     transform="matrix(0.31264363,0,0,0.31264363,65.90126,78.351391)">
    <path
       d="M 454.22,313.78 C 454.22,423.25 365.47,512 256,512 146.53,512 57.78,423.25 57.78,313.78 c 0,-37.65 10.49,-72.86 28.74,-102.83 0,0 25.24,53.86 68.6,36.45 17.05,-6.84 36.46,-26.05 18.16,-57.74 -19.74,-34.17 -9.27,-82.43 34.24,-100.9 C 256,68.18 256,0 256,0 c 4.88,3.13 76.59,50.67 50.28,111.89 -15.72,36.58 -17.6,80.91 15.09,90.71 39.12,11.74 59.77,-42.54 59.77,-42.54 44.59,36.34 73.08,91.7 73.08,153.72 z"
       fill="#fcd703"
       id="path854" />
    <path
       d="M 454.22,313.78 C 454.22,423.25 365.47,512 256,512 V 0 c 4.88,3.13 76.59,50.67 50.28,111.89 -15.72,36.58 -17.6,80.91 15.09,90.71 39.12,11.74 59.77,-42.54 59.77,-42.54 44.59,36.34 73.08,91.7 73.08,153.72 z"
       fill="#fe9100"
       id="path856" />
    <path
       d="m 351.2,416.82 c 0,59.92 -50.51,95.18 -95.2,95.18 -52.56,0 -95.17,-42.61 -95.19,-95.16 0,-0.02 0,-0.02 0,-0.04 -0.24,-19.81 4.04,-43.24 15.97,-70.43 l 38.91,11.38 c 0,-39.56 21.06,-66.17 40.31,-82.23 16.18,-13.48 31.1,-19.52 31.1,-19.52 4.88,58.84 39.4,93.06 51.47,114.71 10.45,18.76 12.63,30.39 12.63,46.11 z"
       fill="#ff7b49"
       id="path858" />
    <path
       d="M 351.2,416.82 C 351.2,476.74 300.69,512 256,512 V 275.52 C 272.18,262.04 287.1,256 287.1,256 c 4.88,58.84 39.4,93.06 51.47,114.71 10.45,18.76 12.63,30.39 12.63,46.11 z"
       fill="#fd435b"
       id="path860" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**As File that you send :**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

In your example, I can display the svg just fine and everything works fine. This sample svg paints the flame completely. The problem occurs to me when the svg contains a jpg or png image, that is, if in addition to the flame that is painted, there is a link to a png image (outside the resource file) that the svg should use as a background. If you open in plain text the .svg, this is a line like this:<image id = "img1" href = "sample.png" />

Comment: In that case, the browser paints the whole image (linked image and lines) correctly, but QT only paints the lines and not the image. I have tried with jpg and png and the behavior is the same in both cases.

Comment: @Tz_d , can you upload your SVG file ?

Comment: Please try with this sample SVG file https://file.io/0Uzvzyu1IQ88. It contains some red and blue crosses and a jpg image in the background. The path for the image inside the svg asumes that both files are in the same path. Thnks!!

Comment: I see page that says `The file you requested has been deleted`

Comment: @Tz_d . I am sure that your SVG file has a problem.

Comment: Please try again: https://file.io/wrpqyOCfW9T9

Comment: I meant to just reference the image inside the SVG (href=path of the image), not to encode the whole image inside the svg. Maybe it is not possible to do what I meant, but the browser opens it ok just with the href to the path,

Comment: I see your zip file. you didn't add the jpg file to svg file ? this should be combined together  and add path of the final SVG to qt code like the example that I attach . means file should be in <svg> tag. not seperated.

Comment: That is precisely my doubt. Is it possible to do it only with the reference ?. For the browser, it is enough to reference the image in the SVG without having to put the entire image file in the SVG, so I had assumed that QT can do it also when rendering it.

Comment: I updated my repo . No QT just understand inside SVG tag as I attached.